# Rearranging Multidex in Pandas (second level of multidex to the second level of a single level column name)

Tags: pandas

What I currently have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"bin1":[1,2,3,4,5,6,'a','b','c','d','e','f'],
                   "bin2":[7,8,9,10,11,12,'g','h','i','j','k','l']})
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["b"+str(i) for i in range(2)], ["v"+str(i) for i in range(1,7)]])
```

OUTPUT:

```
      bin1 bin2
b0 v1    1    7
   v2    2    8
   v3    3    9
   v4    4   10
   v5    5   11
   v6    6   12
b1 v1    a    g
   v2    b    h
   v3    c    i
   v4    d    j
   v5    e    k
   v6    f    l
```

What I want:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"v1":[1,"a"],
                   "v2":[2,"b"],
                   "v3":[3,"c"],
                   "v4":[4,"d"],
                   "v5":[5,"e"],
                   "v6":[6,"f"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                  "v1":[7,"g"],
                   "v2":[8,"h"],
                   "v3":[9,"i"],
                   "v4":[10,"j"],
                   "v5":[11,"k"],
                   "v6":[12,"m"]})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df = df.T
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["bin"+str(i) for i in range(1,3)],["v"+str(i) for i in range(1,7)]])
df = df.T
df.index = ["b0", 'b1']
```

OUTPUT:

```
     bin1                bin2                  
     v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6   v1 v2 v3  v4  v5  v6
b0    1  2  3  4  5  6    7  8  9  10  11  12
b1    a  b  c  d  e  f    g  h  i   j   k   m
```

As we can see, both the dataframes look about the same but because of what I want to do with the frame, it's more convenient to have it in the latter form than the former.

Comment: Simply use `df.unstack(level=1)`.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I can't believe it was that easy.  I've been thinking about this for an embarrassing amount of time.